# Launch a function automatically with spring boot after a regular period of time

Tags: spring-boot

I have an API in my spring boot app that sends an email contains a report 
i can generate i when  click the send button

I want now to automtize this process therefore i want this email to be sent every week without any human interference and i am blocked . How is that possible

thank you for you any help .

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/email/trigger", method = RequestMethod.POST)

public String triggerEmail( @RequestBody Map<String,String> msg) {
  SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();

  String d = msg.get("data");
  String dd = msg.get("mail");
  String ddd = collaborateurDao.find(dd);

  message.setSubject("Test");
  message.setText(d);
  message.setTo("x@s.com");
  message.setFrom("app@sa.com");

  try {
    mailSender.send(message);

    return "{\"message\": \"OK\"}";
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();

    return "{\"message\": \"Error\"}";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Spring Scheduler. Examples

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay =30000)
public void triggerEmail() {... }

// Like Unix cron
@Scheduled(cron="0 0 * * * *")
public void triggerEmail() {... }
```

You can refer to the document for more information
https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/

You can also use OS's dependent schedular like cron jobs in Linux.